# Can't update a sharepoint item while check fields on existing list inside delegates

Tags: sharepoint

I had the next code inside the delegate to create fields

```
delegate(SPList list)
{
    list.Fields.Add(...);
    //I teared off the other same strings 
}
```

I invoked this code in the next way

```
modifyFunction.Invoke(list);

//modifyFunction is a previous delegate, that was declared like
//delegate void ModifyList(SPList list);
```

So, everything was fine, when I try to update item in this list.
But I had to dynamically add fields to the list soon. So, I changed my delegate like

```
delegate(SPList list)
{
    CheckMethod(list);
}

void CheckMethod(SPList list)
{
    if (!list.Fields.ContainsField(...))
    {
        list.Fields.Add(...);
    }
}
```

After this modification (there was no modification in the code anymore) while trying to update an item of this list I have the next exception

```
Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only
```

Such decisions like SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates or SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges didn't give any positive results. Where is the trick? I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit hard to guess what your are exactly doing by analyzing the code parts that your are providing.

1. But I guess that you load the item from the list
2. then you modifiy the list by adding a new field.
3. And then you update the item.

Now, the problem, I guess, is that you have still the same reference to the item after the list has changed.
To solve this problem, you have to reload the item after the modification on the list and then call update on this item.